# Example III.$4$ of Hardy's Course of Pure Mathematics

Tags: analysis, inequality

This problem can be found in Example III.$4$ of Hardy's Course Of Pure Mathematics.
It is given that
$$0<x<\sqrt 2$$
and
$$y>\sqrt 2$$
Further, $$2-x^2<\delta$$
and $$y^2-2<\delta$$
It is required to prove that
$$y-x<\delta$$

Well, I have got no idea on how to solve this. I tried adding the given inequalities up so as to get

$$x^2-y^2>-2\delta$$
I have tried finding an inequality associating the sum of $x$ and $y$ but that was useless.
$$y>\sqrt 2\Rightarrow x+y>x+\sqrt 2>1$$
Thats it. No other significant development.
Note : x, y, $\delta$ are rationals.
Further, Answers using the existence of $\sqrt 2$ will be accepted since Hardy already states that the reader can assume the existence of square roots if he wants to avoid the abstract discussions. I would request to refer the book in case any confusion arises.

Comment: If the existence of $\sqrt2$ is not yet established and is not meant to be used, you should put up a new question with the necessary changes. Currently you have not stated that assumption and your first two inequalities state "$0<x<\sqrt2,y>\sqrt2$" giving the wrong impression to the readers and inviting answers which may not be very useful for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $\delta>0$ since $y^2-2>0$.

1. If $\delta\le2$, you have $\sqrt2<y<\sqrt{2+\delta},\sqrt{2-\delta}<x<\sqrt2$ so$$\begin{align*}y-x&<\sqrt{2+\delta}-\sqrt{2-\delta}\\&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{2+\delta}-\sqrt{2-\delta}\right)\left(\sqrt{2+\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta}\right)}{\sqrt{2+\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta}}\\&=\left[\frac2{\sqrt{2+\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta}}\right]\delta\end{align*}$$Now $(\sqrt{2+\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta})^2=4+2\sqrt{2-\delta}\sqrt{2+\delta}\ge4$, i.e. $\sqrt{2+\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta}\ge2$ and $(\sqrt{2+\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta})^{-1}\le1/2$ so$$\left[\frac2{\sqrt{2+\delta}+\sqrt{2-\delta}}\right]\delta\le\delta$$ which complete the proof. $\blacksquare$

---

2. If $\delta>2$, then the constraint $2-\delta<x^2$ is trivially true and we only have $0<x<\sqrt2,\sqrt2<y<\sqrt{2+\delta}$. Then$$y-x<\sqrt{2+\delta}-0$$so we claim that $\sqrt{2+\delta}\le\delta$. This is equivalent to $2+\delta\le\delta^2\iff(\delta-2)(\delta+1)\ge0$ which is true $\forall\delta>2$.$\blacksquare$

Comment: I don't think that $\sqrt 2$ existence has been confirmed up to the example no. OP mentioned.

Comment: @Koro I haven't read the book but the first inequality itself contains $\sqrt2$. And the OP is apparently satisfied with this answer.

Comment: Probably the OP has overlooked it but the exercise is this: "If $x$ and $y$ are approximations to $\sqrt 2$ by defect and excess respectively, and $2-x^2\lt \delta,y^2-2\lt \delta$, then $y-x\lt \delta$." Please note that "approximations" here is by rational numbers.

Comment: I guess the question demands the use of the assumption . The answer is helpful.